# How do I go about downloading 100,000 torrents?

Tags: command-line, bittorrent

I want to download a large number of torrents on Ubuntu, while keeping a positive ratio on the torrent tracker.

Since various torrent clients won't support that many active torrents (from what I googled), I guess I'll need some sort of a bash solution that would:

1. check if target ratio is reached, exit otherwise
2. select some torrents with the worst ratio (e.g. 100 out of 200)
3. replace them with new not-downloaded torrents

Is there a torrent client that would have a CLI API to do that? Is there a better way to download a large number of torrents?

Comment: I cannot help you, but check out rtorrent. It should have the possibility to control it over a socket and if any normal torrent client can manage 100k torrents, I would bet it's rtorrent.

Comment: Also, even though it's not that comfortable, you can set up rtorrent to deactivate torrents after a certain ratio is reached.